# unable to append string in the directory path

Tags: ruby, unix

> Objective : Rename the folder in directory with today's
>   date

I am using ruby file where I am using linux command to modify directory(ruby version is 2.2) and my code looks like this.

```
require 'date'
class BSDK
  TDATE = Date.today.to_s
  DEFAULT_PATH = "/home/cyborg/bsdk/"
  VERSION = "bsdk-tk-4.2.71"

  def bsdk_processing
    bsdk_version = "#{DEFAULT_PATH}#{VERSION}"
    bsdk_latest = "#{bsdk_version}(#{TDATE})"
    system "mv #{bsdk_version} #{bsdk_latest}"
  end
end

bsdk = BSDK.new
bsdk.bsdk_processing
```

> ```
> Error: 
>     mv: missing destination file operand after '/home/cyborg/bsdk/bsdk-tk-4.2.71'
> ```

When I tried printing bsdk_latest, it is giving me as

```
/home/cyborg/bsdk/bsdk-tk-4.2.71
2019-08-22
```

and not as **/home/cyborg/bsdk/bsdk-tk-4.2.71(2019-08-22)**

Note: we have directory named bsdk-tk-4.2.71 in the path /home/cyborg/bsdk/

Comment: I just changed `system` to `puts` and it shows this: `mv /home/cyborg/bsdk/bsdk-tk-4.2.71 /home/cyborg/bsdk/bsdk-tk-4.2.71(2019-08-21)` ... this is what you indended right?

Comment: No, I want to rename the folder /home/cyborg/bsdk/bsdk-tk-4.2.71 as home/cyborg/bsdk/bsdk-tk-4.2.71(2019-08-22)

Comment: @cyborg: When you print bsdk_latest, it seems that it has a `\n` embedded. What does `bsdk_latest.inspect` show? In addition, you seem to construct a file name which contains parentheses ((#{TDATE})). In this case, you have to quote the argument for the shell (bash or POSIX-shell) in the `mv` command.

Comment: Thanks @user1934428, the issue got resolved , there was new line embedded in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue got resolved as pointed by @user1934428 , there was new line embedded in the VERSION

```
require 'date'
require 'fileutils'
class BSDK
  TDATE = Date.today.to_s
  DEFAULT_PATH = "/home/cyborg/bsdk/"
  VERSION = "bsdk-tk-4.2.71"
  VERSION.strip!

  def bsdk_processing
    bsdk_version = "#{DEFAULT_PATH}#{VERSION}"
    bsdk_latest = "#{bsdk_version}""(#{TDATE})"
    Fileutils.mv("#{bsdk_version}", "#{bsdk_latest}")
  end
end

bsdk = BSDK.new
bsdk.bsdk_processing
```

Comment: This still should give you a syntax error from the shell, since you don't quote bsdk_latest.